# Simple URL redirect after connecting to Wi-Fi Hotspot

Tags: centos7, wifi, captive-portal

This is not as trivial as it looks.
What we have:

- VideoConferencing Terminal with ability to be an AP (Wi-Fi Hotspot)
- Centos 7 Intel Flavoured, pre-installed on that terminal Nginx with
- VideoConferencing WebGUI, pre-installed on that terminal
- DHCP server, pre-installed on that terminal

What we want it to do:
Any user connects with his device (no matter which one) to our Wi-Fi Hotspot, gets a DHCP address, and VCTerminal sends him a URL to be opened, with WebGUI.

Chilispot, Coovaspot, and YFI are not the way to do that, as they manage authentication, and we don't need that auth page. All we need is simple WPA2 Authentication and URL push onto an authenticated device, so it will be able to control the VideoConferencing Software that is preinstalled, via WebGUI.

Put simply, something like a "thank you for using up my free wi-fi".

I searched a lot of info, tried YFI, but it was not what we wanted. So I need help, I think it should be something simple, like really simple, but i can't see the path to the solution.

Thanks in advance!